# An npapi plugin (by Firebreath) can be called by external page, but not the chrome extension page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath, http-proxy

The npapi plugin is a slight modification from FBTestPlugin.

The plugin is currently defined public in manifest. Now, the plugin method can be called from [external page](http://liruqi.sinaapp.com/lovecc.html). But not in any page in the extension, I've tried background page & option page. There is a method **runProxy()** in option page, it does the same thing as the external page, but no method can be found by plugin object.

You may download the chrome extension [here](https://github.com/liruqi/west-chamber-season-3/blob/79f0caee56b4e6e2ab98486350678f1e54594104/west-chamber-proxy/switchylovecc.crx), and try it out.

I debugged in Linux, with command line

```
sudo /opt/google/chrome/chrome --plugin-launcher='xterm -e gdb --args' --user-data-dir='/tmp/liruqi'
```

And found this maybe the problem.

```
[6958:6958:10328544637:ERROR:extension_prefs.cc(955)] Bad or missing pref 'state' for extension 'mpeobcmgemcjlkjkmgialddejohkigkg'
```

But, I wish the plugin can be defined private(only called extension page) for safety reason. how to fix?

Comment: If you want it private, you need to specify "public": false in your manifest.json to start out with. As to why you can't use it from your extension I don't know.

Comment: I will try again with only test page from FBTestPlugin.

Comment: I created a new chrome extension with only one test page, the test page is copied from FBTestPlugin. Still not working. I have to try the original FBTestPlugin in extension. If it still not work, it seems a problem then.

Comment: You could try putting in some plugin that is proven to work in the mentioned case so you can see wether it's a plugin or setup issue.